# How to mirror the official Linux kernel tree in a private gitolite server?

Tags: git, svn, linux-kernel, gitolite

We work with embedded ARM Linux systems and have some SBC based products with custom hardware controlled by them. As such, we need to develop custom kernel drivers and sometimes adapt existing ones. Since we started using Subversion, the chosen strategy was to use a "vendor branch" to keep the vanilla kernels to be used and then create a branch for each product, where we would apply the required patches for the SBC and make our own modifications, resembling very much what is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/q/2312984/1007502

Thankfully, some months ago we decided to migrate our projects to git, so we setup a gitolite server for sharing the projects among the development team, migrating projects from SVN as we need and get more confortable with git. In the special case of the Linux kernel, we think it is interesting to have the option of developing our projects with our gitolite server as the remote, but we'd like to be able to fetch newer kernels from the official tree and eventually contribute something back when it reaches a state which allows that.

On my own machine I can see how to git clone the official kernel tree and create private branches for our products, rebasing them on newer kernels as needed (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2313009/1007502)); but I'm kind of lost on how I should import the official kernel tree into gitolite in a way developers could push/pull from it instead of the official kernel repository, while also being able to keep it in sync with the latter.

Is this a matter of fetching updates from the official tree on our machines and pushing them back to our private gitolite server or is there a more direct approach?

**EDIT: (clarifying the question)**
The main problem is: although I know how to initialize an empty repository for pushing untracked code into gitolite, I'm not sure how to do that for something I cloned from another git repository, such as the official kernel tree.

Once I have a clone of it on my machine, what is the procedure to move it to the private gitolite server?

Then, how is it possible to keep this now "private" kernel tree in sync with the official one?

The idea is that developers should only push to the private tree, eventually only sending patches to the official tree, if ever.

Answer (score 2):

Clone the original kernel source:

```
git clone $KERNEL_URL
```

Add a remote for your private gitolite repository, name it gitolite:

```
git remote add gitolite $GITOLITE_URL
```

Create your private branch

```
git checkout -b our-branch
```

Push your private branch to your private gitolite repository

```
git push gitolite our-branch
```

You're done.

> Is this a matter of fetching updates from the official tree on our machines and pushing them back to our private gitolite server or is there a more direct approach?

It's basically that.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Daniel Baulig. Your procedure is correct, but I realize I failed to stress the real doubt was on how to import the oficial tree into gitolite and keep it updated there for the developers to use, not exactly how to register the new remote and push to it. I edited the question to make it clearer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood, you have 2 remotes of interest:

- The main kernel repository (say, the one in Github)
- Your gitolite repository

This is in fact very simple. You just need to add two remotes in your local repository (which you probably already have for gitolite) with `git remote add ...`. Then, you need to fetch stuff from one remote, merge them with your code and if you are satisfied, push it to the other one. This process is exactly the same taking updates from vanilla kernel and applying to your own remote or the other way around...

...except, you can't push to a repository that's not yours (of course). So when contributing back to the vanilla kernel, you need to send a pull request and convince Linus or one of his servants to accept your request. (Note: Linus doesn't accept github pull requests)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Shahbaz. Like I said to Daniel above, my main trouble is how to move into gitolite the official tree I cloned on my machine (I edited the question to point that out). Once it is "there" on the server, I was unsure if the right way was to somehow make the server pull updates from the official tree, or if I must pull from the official tree to my machine and then push it back to the private server, which seems to be what you said.

Comment: @Claudio, you should definitely pull from the official tree _yourself_ and only push to your private server after merge and making sure there are no conflicts. The other solution probably isn't even possible because the private repository is probably keeping a "bare" git repository.